# dnsmasq not answering IPv6 client DNS queries

Tags: ipv6, dnsmasq

I am running [`dnsmasq`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) 2.90 on FreeBSD 13.3. I use it as a DHCP and as a DNS server and it is almost working.

`dnsmasq` does not answer DNS queries that are sent using IPv6. I am **not** talking about returning addresses for `AAAA` records, but about the client sending the query to `dnsmasq` using IPv6.

I have checked that `dnsmasq` is listening on the IPv6 address (using `sockstat -6`):

```
# sockstat -6 | grep dnsmasq
nobody   dnsmasq    16922 10 udp6   *:53                  *:*
nobody   dnsmasq    16922 11 tcp6   *:53                  *:*
```

I have confirmed that `dnsmasq` is getting the query (and knows the answer) using `log-queries`:

```
Mar 16 23:06:50 bigbrain dnsmasq[16866]: query[A] ct.de from 2a0X:...:6f0d
Mar 16 23:06:50 bigbrain dnsmasq[16866]: forwarded ct.de to 9.9.9.9
Mar 16 23:06:50 bigbrain dnsmasq[16866]: forwarded ct.de to <ISP DNS server 1>
Mar 16 23:06:50 bigbrain dnsmasq[16866]: forwarded ct.de to <ISP DNS server 2>
Mar 16 23:06:50 bigbrain dnsmasq[16866]: reply ct.de is 193.99.144.80
```

I have confirmed basic IPv6 connectivity in the sense that the machine running `dnsmasq` can connect to the client on 53/tcp (*not* what DNS mainly requires, I know, but as close as I could get):

```
# tcpdump -n -i en0 port 53
23:26:31.083294 IP6 2a0X:...:cd84.10679 > 2a0X2:...:6f0d.53: Flags [S], seq 2720024368, win 65535, options [mss 1440,nop,wscale 6,sackOK,TS val 3911032681 ecr 0], length 0
23:26:31.083403 IP6 2a0X2:...:6f0d.53 > 2a0X2:...:cd84.10679: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2720024369, win 0, length 0
```

And when the (same) client sends the query via IPv4 the query is answered...

Is there anything special to configure to make `dnsmasq` answer queries it receives via IPv6?

A *very* similar, unanswered, question I found is the following: [IPv6 dnsmasq dig refused](https://serverfault.com/q/1078767/48229).

Among others, I have read [How to configure dnsmasq for dual stack ipv4/ipv6](https://danielchg.github.io/posts/dnsmasq-for-dualstack/) a couple of times now, but it seems not to mention anything special that needs to be configured.

Note: I have configured two `except-interface=`s, but not on the relevant interface (and queries sent via IPv4 are answered, which would not be the case if the interface was excluded).

### EDIT 1:

Also, the record type that is queried (A, AAAA, MX, TXT, ...) does not make any difference, nor if the queried domain is a "local" one (where `dnsmasq` does not need to forward the query) or not.

### EDIT 2:

The output of `tcpdump` on the interface the query is coming in matches what the client sees: the incoming query can be seen, but no reply whatsoever leaves the interface.

`route -n get` claims that reply packets would leave via the correct interface (the one the query came in on and consequently the one `tcpdump` is monitoring).

So I assume there are no reply packets?!?

### EDIT 3 (solution?):

I found a way to make the queries work/be answered. I am however not sure if this is a workaround or if it is for some reason "expected".

When receiving a query via IPv6, `dnsmasq` will only send a reply if the address the query was sent to is (one of the) addresses the interface where the query was received has configured.

It is, for example, not possible to use 2001:DB8:DEAD:BEEF:F00::1 as the DNS' address when the interface that receives the query is 2001:DB8:DEAD:BEEF:BA7::1 even if 2001:DB8:DEAD:BEEF:F00::1 exists and `dnsmasq` is listening on it.

The same concept works with IPv4: setting the DNS server 192.168.1.1 on a client that is connecting to the server via 192.182.30.1 does result in queries being answered.

Comment: If the query is from IPv6, the reply needs to be IPv6, but the log shows the reply is IPv4, and it makes no sense to send IPv4 to IPv6.

Comment: @RonMaupin: there are cases where IPv4 replies to a query that was sent via IPv6 do make sense. If the client is dual stack for example: it can query the DNS via IPv6, get an IPv4 address back and then connect to that IPv4 address via IPv4.

Comment: What does a network packet capture show?

Comment: @GregAskew: Updated the question (EDIT 2) explaining what tcpdump/packet capture shows (it's congruent with the application layer).

Comment: Next step would be to log queries to confirm it is receiving. `log-queries` in the configuration file.

Comment: @GregAskew: thank you for coming back to this. `log-queries` in fact confirms that `dnsmasq` received the query and knows the answer. An excerpt of the log for a query for `ct.de` is in the question.

Comment: Ah, so the queries aren't sent **to** an address on the resolver.

Comment: I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing, but I would say yes, the queries are sent to an address of the resolver (= the machine running dnsmasq). This machine has multiple (VLAN) interfaces and IP addresses (and is dual stack). The queries are just not sent to the address the machine has in the client's network, but another address of the same machine.